# Spatial distribution of vector polygons

Tags: qgis, vector, distribution

[image]I have two vector layers and I am looking for a tool for spatial distribution of the polygons. polygon 1 is the frame, polygon 2 are objects with different size and distribution. I need an index value for each polygon 1 for statistic calculate neighborhood relationships or spatial distribution of polygon 2. I'm not sure what kind of value it could be, maybe someone have ideas.

Comment: Can you provide use with graphical support, please? As well as what kind of output are you expecting to achieve? How large is your data?

Comment: You should calculate maybe three spatial metrics:  
1. average minimum distance between polygons  
2. average polygon areas  
3. average polygon perimeters